# java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.util.ArrayList com.example.***.***.DBHelper.getAllPersons()

Tags: android, arraylist, nullpointerexception, initialization

I'm trying to retrieve `ArrayList` that consists of Person objects. Here's the part that gives the error in the title (2nd row):

```
ArrayList<Person> persons = new ArrayList<Person>();
persons = myDb.getAllPersons();
```

Here's the Person class:

```
public class Person {

    private int id;
    private String name;
    private int age;
    private double locationX;
    private double locationY;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public double getLocationX() {
        return locationX;
    }

    public void setLocationX(double locationX) {
        this.locationX = locationX;
    }

    public double getLocationY() {
        return locationY;
    }

    public void setLocationY(double locationY) {
        this.locationY = locationY;
    }
}
```

Here's the `DBHelper` class's method that retrieves the `ArrayList` of Person objects:

```
    public ArrayList<Person> getAllPersons() {
        ArrayList<Person> array_list = new ArrayList<Person>();

        //hp = new HashMap();
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor res =  db.rawQuery( "select * from " + ITEMS_TABLE_NAME + " order by item asc", null );
        res.moveToFirst();

        while(res.isAfterLast() == false){
            Person person = new Person();
            person.setName(res.getString(res.getColumnIndex(ITEMS_COLUMN_NAME)));
            person.setAge(res.getInt(res.getColumnIndex(ITEMS_COLUMN_AGE)));
            person.setLocationX(res.getDouble(res.getColumnIndex(ITEMS_COLUMN_LOCATIONX)));
            person.setLocationY(res.getDouble(res.getColumnIndex(ITEMS_COLUMN_LOCATIONY)));
            array_list.add(person);
            res.moveToNext();
        }
        return array_list;
    }
```

What might cause this? I have no idea since the `ArrayList` persons is not null since it is initialized.

Comment: Have you initialized `myDb` object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because yourvariabe `myDb` is null. You maynot be initialized it. Initialize the myDb as an instance of DBHelper class